# WebdriverIO 5 - 'browser.$(...).click is not a function' error

Tags: webstorm, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I am new to WebdriverIO. I was trying to execute my first feature file and I get this error :

```
[chrome  windows #0-0] browser.$(...).click is not a function
[chrome  windows #0-0] TypeError: browser.$(...).click is not a function
```

But I can see the `click()` function listed in the auto suggestions when I type the code in the editor. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Here is my Step definition file :

```
import {Given, Then} from "cucumber";

Given(/^I navigated to RPA Challenge website$/, function() {
    browser.url("http://rpachallenge.com/");
  });

Then(/^I see the submit button$/, function () {
    browser.$("/html/body/app-root/div[2]/app-rpa1/div/div[2]/form/input").click();
    console.log("URL is "+browser.getUrl());
});
```

Here is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "WebdriverIO_2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.6",
    "@wdio/cli": "^5.18.7",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^5.18.6",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.18.7",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^5.18.7",
    "@wdio/sync": "^5.18.7",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "chromedriver": "^80.0.1",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^5.0.2",
    "webdriverio": "^5.18.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.12"
  }
}
```

Output and Error message :

```
C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\WebdriverIO3>node_modules\.bin\wdio wdio.conf.js
2020-03-04T07:18:16.130Z DEBUG @wdio/sync: Couldn't load fibers package for Node v10 and above
2020-03-04T07:18:16.130Z DEBUG @wdio/sync: Couldn't load fibers package for Node v8

Execution of 1 spec files started at 2020-03-04T07:18:18.858Z

2020-03-04T07:18:19.124Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}) on port 4444
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
2020-03-04T07:18:19.940Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: wdio.conf.js
[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:18:22.709Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\WebdriverIO3\features\login.feature
[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:18:24.759Z INFO webdriverio: Initiate new session using the webdriver protocol
[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:18:24.766Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session
[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:18:24.766Z INFO webdriver: DATA { capabilities: { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome' }, firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } }
[3132:23720:0304/124825.906:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: AlwaysAuthorizePlugins
[3132:23720:0304/124825.906:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: DisablePluginFinder
[3132:23720:0304/124825.906:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: PasswordManagerAllowShowPasswords
[3132:23720:0304/124826.015:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: AlwaysAuthorizePlugins
[3132:23720:0304/124826.015:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: DisablePluginFinder
[3132:23720:0304/124826.015:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: PasswordManagerAllowShowPasswords

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53324/devtools/browser/9124ea53-8ac6-483b-8bba-3dcdf611bb28
[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:18:34.702Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND navigateTo("http://rpachallenge.com/")
[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:18:34.703Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/0132136b9c7a963983c93889b31c16d5/url
2020-03-04T07:18:34.703Z INFO webdriver: DATA { url: 'http://rpachallenge.com/' }
[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:18:34.712Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("xpath", "/html/body/app-root/div[2]/app-rpa1/div/div[2]/form/input")
[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:18:34.713Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/0132136b9c7a963983c93889b31c16d5/element
[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:18:34.714Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'xpath',
  value: '/html/body/app-root/div[2]/app-rpa1/div/div[2]/form/input' }
[0-0] Error in "RPA Challenge website launch: scenario 1: Then I see the submit button"
browser.$(...).click is not a function
[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:18:34.775Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND deleteSession()
[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:18:34.777Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/0132136b9c7a963983c93889b31c16d5
[1583306316.590][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1583306316.692][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1583306316.796][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1583306316.898][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100

[0-0] 2020-03-04T07:19:14.197Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '54156a65-2e41-4f61-b9fe-7669cf591b1c' }
[0-0] FAILED in chrome - C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\WebdriverIO3\features\login.feature
2020-03-04T07:19:14.593Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

 "spec" Reporter:
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome  windows #0-0] Spec: C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\WebdriverIO3\features\login.feature
[chrome  windows #0-0] Running: chrome on windows
[chrome  windows #0-0] Session ID: 0132136b9c7a963983c93889b31c16d5
[chrome  windows #0-0]
[chrome  windows #0-0] RPA Challenge website launch
[chrome  windows #0-0]     scenario 1
[chrome  windows #0-0]        ✓ Given I navigated to RPA Challenge website
[chrome  windows #0-0]        ✖ Then I see the submit button
[chrome  windows #0-0]
[chrome  windows #0-0] 1 passing (44.3s)
[chrome  windows #0-0] 1 failing
[chrome  windows #0-0]
[chrome  windows #0-0] 1) scenario 1 Then I see the submit button
[chrome  windows #0-0] browser.$(...).click is not a function
[chrome  windows #0-0] TypeError: browser.$(...).click is not a function
[chrome  windows #0-0]     at World.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\WebdriverIO3\stepDefs/Login.stepdef.js:8:76)
[chrome  windows #0-0]     at World.executeAsync (C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\WebdriverIO3\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:123:21)
[chrome  windows #0-0]     at World.testFrameworkFnWrapper (C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\WebdriverIO3\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\test-framework\testFnWrapper.js:55:28)
[chrome  windows #0-0]     at <anonymous>


Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:55

2020-03-04T07:19:14.600Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2020-03-04T07:19:14.860Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2020-03-04T07:19:14.860Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
```

Comment: Hi, Is your project has `sync` as `true`. For me it looks like `sync` feature of WDIO is not enabled

Comment: How do i set that? In the config file? Also can u explain how both differ?

Comment: I also noticed that this issue not just with click.. none of the functions are working, though i see them in the auto suggestion when i type the code

Comment: Hello @automaticSoldier, when you post this kind of question, wdio config is more important.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because of fibers.

`2020-03-04T07:18:16.130Z DEBUG @wdio/sync: Couldn't load fibers package for Node v10 and above`

The easiest fix for me was to add fibers to the devDependencies.

Also see: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/4913

Comment: Yes. this is the root cause. Thanks for pointing it out. https://webdriver.io/docs/sync-vs-async.html also mentions the issue of fiber in common issues section

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried the same code in the project I have and it works perfectly. I assume the issue is with your config and I have put my config below. Also, you can refer my config from [here](https://github.com/spnraju/demo-webdriverio-cucumberjs/blob/master/config/wdio.conf.js) as well.

I have tried with and without `sync: true`. Works on both occasions.

Cheers!

```js
global.log4js = require('../log4js.config').log4js;

exports.config = {

  runner: 'local',
  specs: [
    './features/*.feature',
  ],
  exclude: [],

  maxInstances: 5,
  capabilities: [{
    'maxInstances': 1,
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      w3c: true,
      args: ['--headless'],
    },
  }, ],
  // logLevel: 'info',
  logLevels: {
    'webdriverio': 'error',
    'webdriver': 'error',
    '@wdio/applitools-service': 'error',
    '@wdio/browserstack-service': 'error',
    '@wdio/devtools-service': 'error',
    '@wdio/sauce-service': 'error',
    '@wdio/mocha-framework': 'error',
    '@wdio/jasmine-framework': 'error',
    '@wdio/local-runner': 'error',
    '@wdio/lambda-runner': 'error',
    '@wdio/sumologic-reporter': 'error',
    '@wdio/cli': 'error',
    '@wdio/config': 'error',
    '@wdio/sync': 'error',
    '@wdio/utils': 'error',
  },
  sync: true,
  coloredLogs: true,
  bail: 0,
  baseUrl: 'https://www.phptravels.net/',
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  services: ['selenium-standalone'],
  framework: 'cucumber',
  // specFileRetries: 1,
  reporters: [
    ['allure', {
      outputDir: 'allure-results',
      disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
      disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
      useCucumberStepReporter: false,
    }],
    ['cucumberjs-json', {
      jsonFolder: 'reports',
      language: 'en',
    }],
  ],
  cucumberOpts: {
    requireModule: ['@babel/register'],
    require: ['./features/step-definitions/*.js'], // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
    backtrace: true, // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
    failAmbiguousDefinitions: true, // <boolean< Treat ambiguous definitions as errors
    dryRun: false, // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
    failFast: false, // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false, // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings
    format: ['pretty'], // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
    colors: true, // <boolean> disable colors in formatter output
    snippets: false, // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
    source: false, // <boolean> hide source uris
    profile: [], // <string[]> (name) specify the profile to use
    strict: true, // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
    tagExpression: '', // <string> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
    timeout: 60000, // <number> timeout for step definitions
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false, // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined
Cannot read property 'waitForClickable' of undefined
```

are all the same issues.

Most likely your variable name is either: not defined, or misspelled.

If you have this type of errors, always refer to whatever you have right before click, getText, waitForClickable.

Example:

```
this.loginPage.loginBtn.click(); loginBtn
```

is where issue is hidden. See if you can go into definition of that selector to verify referencing

Please check this link https://codemify.com/automation/9-Errors-explanation

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
 browser.$(...).click
```

to

```
$().click
```

the click command gets called on the element, not the browser.